# Band alignment of heterojunctions

Tags: electronic-configuration, solid-state-chemistry, semiconductors

I have seen several band bending diagrams in journals and the web. However, I am not sure as to how they align them. Some diagram appear to align the vacuum level and some align them by Fermi Level. I have found that aligning vacuum levels is known as Anderson's Rules and is applied for semiconductor-semiconductor junctions. However, I do not know what the aligning of Fermi level is referred as. What is this convention called?

Also, what are the rules of thumb on deciding on how to align the bands?

Comment: Aligning the Fermi levels is equilibrium. Sadly though, there is no easy rule of thumb - alignments or offsets of the valence, conduction, or both bands are all known.